Marriage in Brahmins
How is marriage is decided between hindu boy and girl according to their gotras for example :
Can a bhardwaj gotra girl marry kaushik gotra boy?

Bhāradvāja and Kauśika are different gotras, so clearly the vivāha of girl and boy respectively from these gotras, wouldn't be a sagotra vivāha, and that is proper. The other important criteria that should be met is that - the boy and girl shouldn't belong to the same piṇḍa. And that the boy and girl should belong to the same jāti or varṇa. In this case, the boy and girl should be both Brāhmaṇas. And the boy should be a dvija, i.e. an upanīta Brāhmaṇa. Plus, the boy should be older than the girl.

These are actually the very basic criteria. Apart from all this, the kula paramparā should be followed.
The kuṇḍalī of both boy and girl should be seen, and all that, should be done as well, in order to determine if the match wouldn't yield future problems.

This question is similar to: If a person is from Parashara gotra but the girl he loves is of Vasishta gotra, are they siblings?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The only criteria regarding Gotras that needs to be followed is that people belonging to same Gotras can't marry.
असपिण्डा च या मातुरसगोत्रा च या पितुः ।
सा प्रशस्ता द्विजातीनां दारकर्मणि मैथुने ॥ ५ ॥
asapiṇḍā ca yā māturasagotrā ca yā pituḥ |
sā praśastā dvijātīnāṃ dārakarmaṇi maithune || 5 ||
She who is not a “sapiṇḍa” of one’s mother, not of the same “Gotra” as his Father, and who is not born of (unlawful) intercourse—has been recommended for marriage.—(5)
Injunction of Manusmriti on marriage.
